# Descending function based on date for each Data on the same Date Codeigniter 3

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter-3

newbie developer here, i was trying to get data by date 'descending', i got successfull to show data by date was descending, but when i input data in the same date, the data is not descending. For example, when i input data on:

| Date | Data |
| --- | --- |
| 5 dec 2022 | 5 |
| 4 dec 2022 | 4 |
| 3 dec 2022 | 3 |
| 2 dec 2022 | 2 |
| 1 dec 2022 | 1 |

it show the data i want to be, it descending start from the lates data i was input. but when i input 5 record on the same date it will show like this:

| Date | Data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 dec 2022 | 1 |
| 1 dec 2022 | 2 |
| 1 dec 2022 | 3 |
| 1 dec 2022 | 4 |
| 1 dec 2022 | 5 |

what i want trying to do is

| Date | Data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 dec 2022 | 5 |
| 1 dec 2022 | 4 |
| 1 dec 2022 | 3 |
| 1 dec 2022 | 2 |
| 1 dec 2022 | 1 |

is that i should add more function for fuction 'oreder_by'? i dont find solution when search it from google. i was newbie in stackoverflow and maybe how i explain my question was bad. so im sory if my language was so stiff

heres my model:

```
public function getDatakartu($id)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('input_name');
        $this->db->join('dbs_card', 'dbs_card.name_card = input_name.id_card');
        $this->db->where('dbs_card.name_card ', $id);
        $this->db->order_by('dbs_card.date', 'desc');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query;
    }
```

Comment: First order by date , then data! .... ORDER BY dbs_card.date DESC, dbs_card.data DESC

Comment: You're welcome! Stay Safe!

Answer (score 1):

```
**just add order by data DESC**




 public function getDatakartu($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('input_name');
    $this->db->join('dbs_card', 'dbs_card.name_card = input_name.id_card');
    $this->db->where('dbs_card.name_card ', $id);
   // try to add order by data also
    $this->db->order_by('dbs_card.date', 'desc');
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'desc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
}
```